# How to filter items in Outlook View Control

Tags: outlook

I'd like to show content of outlook inbox folder filtered to particular subject using Outlook View Control. I try different parameters to Filter and Restriction parameters (like "Subject"="Test", Subject:"Test" etc), but it don't work. All items are displayed. I'm testing it on Outlook 2010 32 bit.

Thanks for suggestions

Sample Code:

```xml
 <html>
    <head>
    <title>Outlook view filter test</title>
    </head>
    <body topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 scroll=no>
        <OBJECT classid=CLSID:0006F063-0000-0000-C000-000000000046 id=tasks height="30%" width="50%">
            <param name="Folder" value="Inbox">
            <param name="Namespace" value="MAPI">
            <param name="Restriction" value="[subject]:'Test'">
            <param name="Filter" value="[subject]:'Test'">
            <param name="DeferUpdate" value="0">
        </OBJECT>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `Filter`, as the documentation says:

> represents the Distributed Authoring and Versioning (DAV) Searching and Locating (DASL) statement used to restrict the display to a specified subset of data. Read/write

Instead just use `Restriction`.  With `Restriction` `=` means contains, see documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff865641.aspx

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Outlook view filter test</title>
    </head>
    <body topmargin=0 leftmargin=0 scroll=no>
        <OBJECT classid=CLSID:0006F063-0000-0000-C000-000000000046 id=tasks height="30%" width="50%">
            <param name="Folder" value="Inbox">
            <param name="Namespace" value="MAPI">
            <param name="Restriction" value="[Subject]='Test'">
            <param name="DeferUpdate" value="0">
        </OBJECT>
    </body>
</html>
```